# How do I make my scrolling smooth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have written a scroller function which will scroll one div inside another one. The idea is to use the setInterval method to change the margin of the inner element to simulate a scrolling div.

The problem I am facing is that the scrolling is not entirely smooth. Sometimes it stops for a split-second and then it resumes. What can I do to remove these random hiccups? (I am moving 1px per 20 milliseconds)

Comment: http://github.com/niyazpk/HTML-Content-Scroller/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 1):

three comments that might make an answer:

i see you are already using jQuery. it has scroll functions that have been smooth for me.

have you tried fractional positions? as in scrollerMarginTop -= 0.7;

also, you should probably clearInterval() unless the user can move the div and you want it to resume scrolling back into place.

if it works great until you interact with it, consider clearing the interval and waiting until interaction occurs and re-intervaling.

hth

Answer (score 0):

It was quite some time ago that you asked this question, but if you haven't found a working solution you could try [Smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com) which is a jQuery plugin that does exactly what you describe: scroll one div inside another one.